# how to get particular metadata tags from files using apache tika

Tags: java, linux, file, metadata, apache-tika

I have some files in a folder(sample.pdf, sample.html etc) and i am using following Apache tika command to extract metadata.

```
java -jar tika-app.jar -m -j /sample/sample.pdf > test.txt
```

after executing this command i am able to get all the metadata tags for sample.pdf file, but my requirement is to get particular tags like author, title etc. please suggest me how to use Apache tika to get particular metadata tags.

Thanks

Comment: `xpdf` provides a utility `pdfinfo` that provides metadata information for a PDF.

Comment: Put metadata in temporary file, grep for the metadata key of interest, use awk to split out the value? Or something more specific / in a different language / etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract metadata Names as follow (my example is for parsing XML file, you can simply change it to PDF parser or use auto detect parser:

```
//detecting the file type
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
File inFile = new File("example.xml");
FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(inFile);
ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();

//Xml parser
XMLParser xmlparser = new XMLParser(); 
xmlparser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, pcontext);

System.out.println("Metadata of the document:");
String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();//Now we have all the metadata tags here

for(String name : metadataNames) {
    if (name == "Your Particular Tag"){ //here you can check if the tag names are the particular ones you need and do what you want with them
        System.out.println(name + ": " + metadata.get(name));
    }
}
```